# Pull root image from remote linux

Tags: linux, tar

I have switches running PicOS-Linux. This pretty much Linux with Open vSwitch and Busybox. Updates are handled by loading an image of the full file system. So a system image is pretty much just a .tar.gz containing the whole file system starting from root.

I want to customize these update images and for doing so I want to pull a full system image from the switch. I tried making the .tar.gz on the machine itself but that doesn't work because the switch doesn't have enough storage. I tried to pull everything using ftp and a little script, but that doesn't work either because it destroys the permissions and owners. Also it causes problems with symlinks.

Do you have any other ideas how I could get a system image?

The switch has very little free memory and does not have an USB-port or therelike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `tar` and `ssh`, you can create a tarball and send it directly over ssh, by specifying `-` or `/dev/stdout` as the output file:

```
ssh yourswitch "tar cvzf - /" > switch.tgz
```

Comment: It tends to work fairly well, but you'll find that you need to add things (typically to exclude directory *content* from /proc etc.) you shouldn't even need to specify   f -   as without the 'f' option it will go to ardour anyway. I've used this technique plenty of times for things like P2V. Rsync is also useful in this regard.

Comment: @CameronKerr bsdtar still defaults to the tape device if no -f is given. As for /proc, there is -x

Comment: you can use dropbear for ssh or even busybox's `nc` the same way

Comment: @CameronKerr: yep, I had to exclude /proc and a few other things but it worked quite well all together. I reflashed the image to the switch just to test that it worked and it did. Pretty happy about that ^^

Comment: @technosaurus: I'll have a look, thanks for the hint!